# Dynamically add data to an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, alteryx

I am currently trying to backfill data from an S3 bucket, to SQL server using Alteryx. Unfortunately, there is a lot of data and running a month at a time crashes our server.

I'm trying to find a way to build a SQL statement, that will look for a MAX() date that is currently in the dataset, and then subsequently add/append the next 3+ days of data to my table. Is this functionality possible, and if so, any suggestions on the query?

I would like to then schedule this query to run overnight so we can start populating this table.

Comment: Sure this is possible. You would use DATEADD to add 3 days to your max date.

Comment: I originally was thinking DATEADD but it looks like DATEADD is in the SELECT statement of the query, so I've been trying to build out the below. Would this work? Or how would DATEADD be applied/                                                                                                                       
SELECT *
FROM tables
WHERE date > CAST(MAX(date) + 3 as date)

Comment: You should use DATEADD instead of just adding 3 to a datetime. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations But yes that is pretty much what you need to do.